# Could not make this code cross compile between MSVC 2015 and GCC 7.3

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++, language-lawyer

While I was writing code for my project I found a very weird situation in which my **C++11** code could not be cross compiled between **GCC 7.3** and **MSVC 2015**. The case is basically this one:

```
// .H file

template <typename X>
struct Outer {
    X x = {};

    template <typename Y>
    struct Inner {
        Y y = {};
        Inner& operator++();
    };
};

// .INL file

template <typename X>
template <typename Y>
inline Outer<X>::Inner<Y>&
    Outer<X>::Inner<Y>::operator++()
{
    ++y;
    return *this;
}

// .CPP file

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Outer<int>::Inner<int> a;
    ++a;
    std::cout << a.y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

GCC will not complain about the above code. But MSVC will, and the error would be:

```
warning C4346: 'Inner': dependent name is not a type note: prefix with
'typename' to indicate a type error C2061: syntax error: identifier
'Inner' error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' error C2447:
'{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

As suggested by the MSVC compiler itself, writing the `typename` keyword on the return type will fix the issue:

```
template <typename X>
template <typename Y>
inline typename Outer<X>::Inner<Y>&
Outer<X>::Inner<Y>::operator++()
{
    ++y;
    return *this;
}
```

But now, quite surprisingly, GCC will not compiler anymore, and its error is:

```
error: non-template 'Inner' used as template
     inline typename Outer<X>::Inner<Y>&
                               ^~~~~ note: use 'Outer<X>::template Inner' to indicate that it is a template error: expected
unqualified-id at end of input
```

Again, as suggested by the compiler itself, I tried to add the keyword `template` to the return type, and this will fix the issue for GCC:

```
template <typename X>
template <typename Y>
inline typename Outer<X>::template Inner<Y>&
Outer<X>::Inner<Y>::operator++()
{
    ++y;
    return *this;
}
```

But this fix will now break once again the MSVC build, and the error from the compiler is:

```
error C2244: 'Outer<X>::Inner<Y>::operator ++': unable to match
function definition to an existing declaration note: see declaration
of 'Outer<X>::Inner<Y>::operator ++' note: definition note:
'Outer<X>::Inner<Y> &Outer<X>::Inner<Y>::operator ++(void)' note:
existing declarations note: 'Outer<X>::Inner<Y>
&Outer<X>::Inner<Y>::operator ++(void)'
```

This time around, I just stopped as the compiler error message is not helpful, as the reported mismatch between definition and declaration does not exist: the signatures given by the compiler itself are perfectly matching.

At this point, not knowing any better solution, I decided to just define the function inside the Inner class scope in the .H file, and that would work for both GCC and MSVC. But some questions still remain: who is right? GCC or MSVC? Or is the C++ standard that in this case is too ambiguous?

Comment: Use conditional compilation.

Comment: @jxh that wouldn't answer the "*who is right?*" question I believe

Comment: @rustyx: Need language lawyer tag then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work for all compilers I have tested:

```
template <typename X>
template <typename Y>
inline auto Outer<X>::Inner<Y>::operator++() 
    -> Inner<Y> &
{
    ++y;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Paraphrasing @rustyx, that doesn't answer the "*who is right?*" question I believe ;-)

Comment: @jxh I agree. But there are two questions in one here, and I answered the first: making it cross compile between the two compilers. Maybe a new question should be asked

Answer (score 2):

VS 2017 ([15.9 update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2018/11/15/vs-2017-15-9-update/)) builds this code just fine. Upgrade to the latest version which is more C++11/C++14 compliant than VS 2015 Update 3.

```
cl /permissive- /W4 /EHsc t.cpp
```

> Check out the [Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) to see if the license meets your requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately my project needs to support MSVC 2015.

Comment: Code built with VS 2015 can link with code built with VS 2017 as they are binary compatible, although you need to use the latest version of the CRT in VS 2017 to ensure everything links up. Otherwise you'll just need to modify your code.

Comment: So this basically confirms that it is the MSVC 2015 implementation to be the incorrect one I guess...

Comment: [CLang](https://tio.run/##fZFNT8MwDIbv@RWWkCagYuOclVy4MAnBju0xas2IlKZR6kpUE7@95GuBw4QvcV7beZ8knbUPnZbmtK67HWxf4ENpZIxwsFoSQk2LRSMHhEawidzcEbzPhA7ODHw08AVPcP7es7i9MteKWMmzB2PKbIgWljx/UWLHBkaLTtLoqur2LhV9T7AJmIe3139Br2Moo5VBKFK8R90Izkt/NK9bsYmOvw0XnfO/XCzdo6qWROiQZmfgnj7V5GET6/PxmFlvlOn03HsqNfrnQDkI5qEIBqlMOS2ZernYhhzkPnvlZKKe826cCeoa5HYJS9TQ9Dr/RuZ59Czr@gM) also accepts it, so that makes MSVC 2015 the odd man out.

Comment: [CLang](https://tio.run/##fZHBSsQwEIbveYoBYVHL7nrO1ly87ILoHttjSEcNpNOSTsGy@Ow1SWMRXJxLJv/M5P@SmL7fGqfpfZ73e9gd4c06FIKx7Z1mhJKnHkm3CJUSA/vRMLyOjB4uAkJU8AmPcPk6iLS9MlerVMmzJ6J1NkYNU57/UVLHBroevebOF8Xt3VIMPdEmYp5env8FvY5hyVlCWKV0j7JSUibPslabZPRXl/I3jljwi2JawDzy6Anu@cMOgXFBfDqfM@KNJePGJsDYLrwC6laJwMLQakvraYtpkFfbmIM@ZK@cDNxIabqRoSxB76a4JA2pcfkTMs9DYJnnbw) also complains about the missing `template` keyword before `Inner`.

Comment: @jxh yes, CLang, apparently from version 5.0 on, wants both the `template` and the `typename` keywords. I am curious about which compiler is getting this thing right between the three.